# Pointers in array and structure

Tags: c++

I want to print the data using pointers i've done it using for but not getting how to use pointer in array of structures so is there any one who can help me and get me out of it....

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    struct employee
    {
        char e_name[20];
        int e_id;
        int e_age;
        char e_degree[20];
    };
    struct employee e[3];
    int i = 1;
    cout << "Enter the Employee Data:" << endl;
    for (i=1; i<4; i++)
    { 
       cout << "Data of Employee #" << i << ":" << endl;
       cout << "Enter Employee Name:" << endl;
       cin >> e[i].e_name;
       cout <<  "Enter Employee ID:" << endl;
       cin >> e[i].e_id;
       cout <<  "Enter Employee age:" << endl;
       cin >> e[i].e_age;
       cout <<  "Enter Employee Highest Degree (Graduation/Masters/Mphil/):" << endl;
       cin >> e[i].e_degree;
     }
    struct employee *ptr;
     ptr = &e[3];
     for (i=1; i<4; i++)
      {
       cout << e[i].e_name, e[i].e_id, e[i].e_age, e[i].e_degree;
       cout << "Data of Employee #" << i << ":" << endl;
       cout << "Name:    " << ptr->e_name << endl;
       cout << "ID:   " << ptr->e_id << endl;
       cout << "Age:  " << ptr->e_age << endl;
       cout << "Degree:  " << ptr->e_degree << endl;
      }
     getch();
     return 0;
     }
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: the problem is when i run the code in the output the employee index changes but the data remain the same that is for employee 1... and i'm not sure about pointers i structures and arrays.

Comment: actually i need help in displaying the employee data using pointers...

Comment: @attiqa `for (i=1; i<4; i++)`  Arrays start at index 0, not 1.  You also have `ptr = &e[3];`  The advice is to not try to simulate 1-based arrays in C++, as it is very easy to make off-by-one mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays start with index of 0, not 1.  Pointer to the end is not helpful either, you want to point to the beginning of the array and increment each iteration through your print loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    struct employee
    {
        char e_name[20];
        int e_id;
        int e_age;
        char e_degree[20];
    };
    struct employee e[3];
    int i = 0;
    cout << "Enter the Employee Data:" << endl;
    for (i=0; i<3; ++i)
    { 
       cout << "Data of Employee #" << (1+i) << ":" << endl;
       cout << "Enter Employee Name:" << endl;
       cin >> e[i].e_name;
       cout <<  "Enter Employee ID:" << endl;
       cin >> e[i].e_id;
       cout <<  "Enter Employee age:" << endl;
       cin >> e[i].e_age;
       cout <<  "Enter Employee Highest Degree (Graduation/Masters/Mphil/):" << endl;
       cin >> e[i].e_degree;
     }
     struct employee *ptr = e;
     for (i=0; i<3; ++i, ++ptr)
      {
       cout << e[i].e_name, e[i].e_id, e[i].e_age, e[i].e_degree;
       cout << "Data of Employee #" << (1+i) << ":" << endl;
       cout << "Name:    " << ptr->e_name << endl;
       cout << "ID:   " << ptr->e_id << endl;
       cout << "Age:  " << ptr->e_age << endl;
       cout << "Degree:  " << ptr->e_degree << endl;
      }
     getch();
     return 0;
     }
```

Comment: That's rich.  Why -1?

Comment: thanks for saving me... i was like drowning in the sea of pointers.. thanks for your help... :)

Answer (score 1):

Your pointer is pointing to the third element of an array. Having that in mind, your for loop will print out the third element three times. You should pass your array identifier e(also a pointer) to "ptr", and then increment "ptr" in for loop. That's called pointer arithmetic.

More info: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_arithmetic.htm

Also, since C++ is OO language, i would recommend using classes instead of structures.

Answer (score 0):

```
 struct employee *ptr;
 ptr = &e[3];
 for (i=1; i<4; i++)
 {
   cout << e[i].e_name, e[i].e_id, e[i].e_age, e[i].e_degree;
   cout << "Data of Employee #" << i << ":" << endl;
   cout << "Name:    " << ptr->e_name << endl;
   cout << "ID:   " << ptr->e_id << endl;
   cout << "Age:  " << ptr->e_age << endl;
   cout << "Degree:  " << ptr->e_degree << endl;
 }
```

This code, probably, doesn't do what you expect. It's because `ptr` always points to the same thing (e[3]).

replace it with:

```
 struct employee *ptr;
 for (i=1; i<4; i++)
 {
   ptr = &e[i-1]; //i-1 because 0 is actually the first element
   .... //your code
 }
```

---

You can do the same thing by setting pointer to the first element of your array, and increase it in your loop.

Comment: how "0" is the first element the index is initialized by 1... so 1-1=0 and no data for i=0....

Comment: You are populating the array incorrectly.  In C and C++ arrays start indexing with 0 not 1.